# Loading a JSON file containing parameters used by the code in a javascript web page

Tags: javascript, json

I'm developping a web UI in javascript. Data are stored in a remote DB, accessed by an API.
I need extra data that are not stored in the DB, and I can't create any table or store any structured data in it.

I started by creating arrays in the code but it quickly becomes unreadable and overwhelming, leading to an awful mix of code and data in my JS files.

So I created a JSON file to store them, looking like that.

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "arrays": {
        "array1": [
            ["key1","value1",0],
            ["key2","value2",1]
        ],
        "array2": [
            ["key1","value1",0],
            ["key2","value2",1]
        ]
    },
    "templates": {
        "template1": {
            "property1": 2,
            "property2": "value2",
            "property3": true
        },
        "template2": {
            "property1": 3,
            "property2": "value3",
            "property3": false
        }
    }
}
```

I coded a simple parser, loading the data in a global JSON object at the beginning of the code, with a **synchronous** `XMLHttpRequest` as I need the data to be available from multiple functions at any time during execution.

```
var jsonDB = JSON.parse(getXML('https://example.com/data.json'));
// Where getXML is a function using a sync XMLHttpRequest to get and return the file.
```

Then I can use these data as follow:

```
function X (param0, param1, param2) {
    if ( param0 == jsonDB[param1][param2].property1 ) {
        return jsonDB[param1][param2].property2;
    }
}
```

The JSON file is around 90 kbytes, loaded very quickly. From my perspetive, the architecture is good : code is clean, separated from this data ; and data are structured, easily maintained. From a user perspective, the load time is insignificant.

However, I'm getting an annoying warning:

```
[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
```

Then, I created a **async xhr** function to load the file. But the number of times it's called is so big that it ends up in unresolved requests and empty fields in the rendered HTML. I don't know how the async xhr is caching the JSON file, but the result is that responses are getting lost.

I eventually tried to used await/sync and Promises but I didn't mange to get something working as expected without rewritting the whole code, which is not an option.

I need to load a JSON file, once and only once, from the beggining of the code execution to make it available from anywhere, without getting a warning from the browser. Exactly like if it was a .js lib or a css file. It's ok the block execution for few ms but it's not ok to have a warning.

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

**Note:** I've seen many questions turning around loading JSON in JS on the site, but none was addressing this precise issue (JSON as variables) and all tests I've done with await/sync failed.

Comment: why don't you put your data in a js file, and then simply use `<script src="dataJSON.js" ...` in your pages ?

Comment: Because the file contains JSON formated data, no javascript. Can't be parsed by the interpreter. Moreover I'd like to keep the extension for my IDE.

Comment: so just add them your name! `var jsonDB = {"version": "1.0", "encoding": "UTF-8", "arrays": {...`

Comment: damned, looks like it's working fine after a quick test. So many hours for `var jsonDB=...`... I feel stupid. Thank you Mister Jojo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is so simple, I ashamed.

1. Add a variable declaration at the beginning of the JSON data file.

```
jsonDB = {"version": "1.0", "encoding": "UTF-8", "arrays": {...
```

2. Change the file extension to `.js` for correct interpretation in the IDE (I'm using Visual Studio Code). Although the IDE is still linting the JSON data correctly (as Javascript variable), there're 2 drawbacks : JSON syntax highlighting is not applying anymore ; Visual Studio Code 'Outline' panel is not usable anymore as the JSON is not interpreted, making navagation within data difficult.
3. Load the JSON file just like any other javascript file.

```
<script src="dataJSON.js" ...
```