# Best way to handle fix datasets

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Lets say we have a dataset with countries and their phone prefixes. Something in the lines of:

```
var countryPhonePrefixes = [
    {
        'name': 'Spain',
        'prefix': '+34'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Austria',
        'prefix': '+43'
    },
    // and so forth
];
```

This would result in over 1000 lines in your development code (before minifying). My question is, are there any best practices regarding how to fetch or initialize datasets like these?

I have though of:

- Leaving this in the code and using some collapse function that almost every IDE has so it does not bother too much.
- Having it in a separate JavasScript file, where you could also do some other functionallity related to the dataset. The JavasScript libraries work more or less.
- Using AJAX to retrieve it. E.g.: `jQuery.getJSON()` from a `.json` file in your server; `xhttp.open()` & `xhttp.send()` to and API in your server, etc.

Some extra context: I need to use this dataset for generating the `<option>`s for a country phone prefix selector in several forms throughout the application. There is already an icon select in the application that works like the first solution I proposed.

Comment: keep it simple.

Comment: extra file, then ajax or compiled into the soure using webpack??

Comment: Something that big should definitely be in its own file, at least if you're trying for serious development. If it's static, bundle it with the other Javascript (use something like Webpack) and send it all to the client at once. If it's dynamic, either use a network request, or send it in the HTML, like in its own script tag.

Comment: I'm more concern about how you manage to type in all the `countryPhonePrefixes`

Comment: @appleapple Got the countries from here https://github.com/mledoze/countries/blob/master/countries.json

Comment: @JosephPernerstorfer it's fine, then. If it doesn't bother you, there is really no need to move it out.

Comment: @appleapple thats the thing, it does bother me, and I wanted to know if there is a better approach to loading big, inmmutable arrays. Performance wise and from a readability point of view

Comment: @CertainPerformance We load different ```.js`` depending on wich page the user requests. We also lazyload certain files if required. So, I think I will have it in its own file, and load it via request when needed, and let the browser handle the caching... If you write an answer from your comment I would accept it.

Comment: @JosephPernerstorfer it depends on the situation. But from your previous response I think you already have your answer. (then why bother ask us :(

Comment: @appleapple I got my answer from CertainPerformance's comment

Comment: @JosephPernerstorfer which you list in the Q.

Comment: no need to use ajax => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294612/loading-a-json-file-containing-parameters-used-by-the-code-in-a-javascript-web-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1000 lines of Javascript data should definitely be in its own file - for development, it's too large to exist in the same area as script logic.

If the data is static, then you can save (and maintain) it in a separate file, while importing the data in other files. Use a module bundler like Webpack to package the script together into a single `.js` which gets delivered to the client.

If the data isn't static (and, for example, can change from one request to another), then it can't be bundled together with the other data. Rather, you can either:

- Send the data to the client with a network request. This *works*, but slightly increases the amount of time required for the data to be usable.
- Another option is to send the data in its own `<script>` tag. Then have your other Javascript parse the script tag, eg:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(
  document.querySelector('script[type="application/json"]').textContent
);

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script type="application/json">[{"foo":"bar"}]</script>
```

Comment: And what about `<script>const data = [{"foo":"bar"}]</script>` ?

Comment: You *could* do that, but that would require polluting the global scope with an extra variable. Putting just the data alone into a tag that gets parsed on demand is a better solution, IMO.

Comment: I tried: `<script type="application/json" src="test.json"></script>` (with content=`[{"foo":"bar"}]`) and that sends me back an empty chain, did I miss something ?

Comment: The `src` of a script tag should always be Javascript. JSON alone won't do anything - even if it happens to be sent with the Javascript MIME type (which it probably won't be), it'll just be an unused expression, and won't be accessible to anything else. You have to either *inline* the data, like with the code in the answer (don't put it in a separate file), *or* you have to make an explicit network request (with Javascript) to the endpoint and then parse the response.

Answer (score 1):

If you access the prefixes with `name`, you could take an object with `name` as key and `prefix` as value.

This approach shortens the code and allows easy access to the prefix.

```
countryPhonePrefixes = {
    Spain: '+34',
    Austria: '+43'
};
```

Comment: Sure, that makes the code more concise, but I don't think that was the question

Comment: I only loop it to generate ``<option>``s, it is the only thing I would use this array for.

Comment: then an array would be best.